# XSLT read from two different sources (XML file and Excel sheet)

Tags: java, xml, excel, xslt

Is there a way I can make my `xslt` file get input from two different sources? One source is a XML file and the other is an Excel sheet. I need to get data from both of them. For example, I have this `xslt`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Data/AAA">
        <xsl:for-each select=".">
            <Data xmlns="MyProtocol.xsd">
                <BBB>
                    <Id><xsl:value-of select="Id"/></Id>
                    <Timestamp><xsl:value-of select="Timestamp"/></Timestamp>
                    <xsl:if test="Transfer">
                        <Transfer><xsl:value-of select="Transfer"/></Transfer>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <Code>0</Code>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Sequence/Number">
                        <Result>
                            <Number><xsl:value-of select="."/></Number>
                            <Code>0</Code>
                        </Result>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </BBB>
            </Data>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Excel Sheet:

```
     A                  B

1    Number      |      Code
     -----------------------
2    5556667777         1
3    5559877890         1
4    5552835291         0
.    ...
.    ...
.    ...
```

The xml:

```
<Data xmlns="MyProtocol.xsd">
    <AAA>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Timestamp>2016-31-12</Timestamp>
        <Sequence>
            <Number>5556667777</Number>
            <Number>5559877890</Number>
            <Number>5552835291</Number>
        </Sequence>
    </AAA>
</Data>
```

From here, I want to change the `xslt` for the `<xsl:for-each select="Sequence/Number">` part. I would like to to the following:

- Read the `<Number>` from the xml file
- Check if that number is in the Excel sheet
- Assign the correct `<Code>` number for that number in the `xslt`

I have code where I can pass the XML file so that the xslt can make a new XML file according to the xslt; however, I can't figure out how to do the above.

Here's the code I have:

```
File stylesheet = new File(xsltFilePath);
InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes()));

Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        .newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputSource);

StreamSource stylesource = new StreamSource(stylesheet);
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(stylesource);

StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(stringWriter));

return stringWriter.toString();
```

The above code works fine if I just use a xml file. How can I achieve what I described above? Thanks in advance!

---

**Update:** Got it to work by turning the Excel sheet into a xml file (through Java code) and then following [Martin Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen)'s answer below.

Comment: If you are able to save down your excel file to some form of xml, you could probably use the document() function : http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp. The other way to do that would be to write your own java extension. (https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html) Note that you need the enterprise version of saxon for that, you can use the open source version of xalan though.

Comment: If I converted the Excel sheet to XML like this: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e3a3a4e254af80402ffd30d6a806e078, can I format my `xslt` for `<Code>` under `<xsl:for-each select="Sequence/Number">` to say something like `value-of select="code_from_number"`? I can't find anything. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have the XML data exported as an XML document you can pull in the the second document with e.g.

```
<xsl:param name="sheet-uri" select="'sheet.xml'"/>
<xsl:param name="sheet-doc" select="document($sheet-uri)"/>
```

and then

```
                <xsl:for-each select="Sequence/Number">
                    <Result>
                        <Number><xsl:value-of select="."/></Number>
                        <Code>
                           <xsl:variable name="referenced-code" select="$sheet-doc//Sequence[Number = current()]/Code"/>
                           <xsl:choose>
                             <xsl:when test="$referenced-code">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$referenced-code"/>
                             </xsl:when>
                             <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
                           </xsl:choose>
                        </Code>
                    </Result>
                </xsl:for-each>
```